# filter by how many + signs are in a row in r

Tags: r, filter

Is it possible to filter by how many + signs are in a row in r and also if a certain letter (or word) is in the row?

Like for example if I only wanted to filter rows with 2 or more + signs and they also have to include c.

Example input:

```
a + b + c 
a + b 
a + c 
a + b + b 
a + c + c 
a + b + c + d
```

Example output:

```
a + b + c 
a + c + c 
a + b + c + d
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "+ signs in a row".  "In a row" implies there might be other signs that break the count, like `a + b - c + d + e` has 3 + signs but only 2 in a row... but none of your sample inputs have anything like that. Is "in a row" a red herring, or meaningful?

Comment: I simply meant row of the data. So I wanted to filter by how many + signs there are in each row of the dataset. I should have included sample data to make that more clear but was in a rush when I posted the question. The example input is supposed to be 6 rows and the example output is 3 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use `str_count` to get the number of `+` in each element of the column, check whether it is greater than 1, as well as detect for 'c' character in the column

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    filter(str_count(col1, fixed("+")) >1, str_detect(col1, fixed("c")))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 1
  col1         
  <chr>        
1 a + b + c    
2 a + c + c    
3 a + b + c + d
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("a + b + c", "a + b", "a + c", "a + b + b", 
"a + c + c", "a + b + c + d")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible base R solution:

```
df[nchar(gsub("[^+]", "", df$col1)) > 1 &
      grepl("c", df$col1, fixed = TRUE), ]
```

**Output**

```
  col1         
  <chr>        
1 a + b + c    
2 a + c + c    
3 a + b + c + d
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(col1 = c("a + b + c", "a + b", "a + c", "a + b + b", 
"a + c + c", "a + b + c + d")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```